# Вызвать функцию с аргументами из массива

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет вызывать другую функцию и передавать ей аргументы из массива.

```js
function call(func, args){
    //...
}

call(someFunc, ["Test", 5, -8]);
//должно быть равнозначно someFunc("Test", 5, -8)
```

Comment: Покажите что вы уже пробовали сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const call = (callback, args) => {
    callback(...args)
}

const cb = (...args) => {
    console.log(args)
}
```